# Garage door - sunlight & garage door sensor

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

Can direct sunlight interrupt the sensor, preventing the door from going all the way down?  At night, early mornings or on overcast days my garage door goes up and down with no problem.  However, when the sun is out the door will go down partially then back up.  What can cause this?

Comment: When this improper reversal occurs is it always at the same door position or  does it vary? I had some grass and cobwebs on the bottom of my door cause reversal when the grass passed through the beam to the electric eye. Absent this it does seem possible that stray sunlight could cause problems. One test for this might be to temporarily mount a tube (paper towel cardboard tube or piece of landscape drain) so as to shield the detector from stray light. See if the door works with this when it doesn't without. Maybe realign the source and detector, but I admit that I don't know how to do tthis.

Comment: I suppose that at the time of brightest sunlight on the detector and it's reversing, you could shield the sensor with a large object outside the door and see if this has an effect.

Comment: I recently installed a Chamberlain opener, and the instructions clearly recommended putting the sensor on the side of the door that would best avoid direct sunlight. Possibly you could swap sides with sender/receiver.

Comment: What is the procedure for optimizing the alignment of the source and sensor? Can one put a DC voltmeter on the output of the sensor and then adjust the source for maximum signal?

Comment: When I installed a Genie 20 years ago I constructed sturdy boxes around the source and sensor. This was to prevent them getting damaged or knocked out of alignment, but it may have been helping to shield them from stray light as this garage opens to the south. There are however trees which shade the garage door somewhat. The top and back of these  "hoods" is 2 x 6 for strength. The inside panel on each is 3/8" plywood screwed on so it can be removed for adjusting without removing the entire box.

Comment: Most of the sensor are basically a switch triggered by light 1064nm being the most common wavelength. I have seen sun light and even a full moon cause the safety to reverse. Adding 1" of black tubing / hose on the reciever will help reduce stray light problems. If not labeled the transmitter or emitter usually has 2 wire connections and receiver has 3 connections (not always but many are wired this way.

Comment: Please post the  motor/sensor/etc. model.  And if Steve F's suggestion doesn't help, make sure that the direct sun isn't heating something which leads to track binding.

Answer (score 2):

My Genie suffered the same issue, sunlight "blinding" the system.

After reading all the "fixes", it occurred to me that the one simple remedy would be to simply reverse the devices, putting the receiver pointing away from the sunlight instead of into it.

The opener doesn't care which way it's laid out; it's totally arbitrary, at the whim of the installer.

The wiring on the Genie is very simple, with two leads to each device. This can be done in either of two ways: "home runs", (a pair of leads to each device), or a "loop", (one lead going to one device, then looping over to the other one). Both circuits are electronically the same. The red wire connects to the white with black stripe and the white wire connects to the white-only wire.

It took ten minutes to do, and I didn't have to build any boxes or use any toilet paper tubes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your garage door opener is most likely radio-based.  But the transmitters are very low power.  It is quite possible for atmospherics to affect radio waves.

Sometimes you can build a metal box around the receiver which will make it receive signals from predictable directions.

Comment: The problem is with the safety sensors at the door's closed position.